# React state not updating

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, state

So I'm making a simple React application that needs to show a modal when something is clicked. I use react-modal to achieve this and the modal is showing but I'm not able to close it again. Here's the code:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import Paper from "./Paper";

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Paper title={"Title"} notes={"Notes"}/>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

and the Paper definition:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import Modal from 'react-modal';

    class Paper extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {modalIsOpen: false};
            this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
            this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
        }

        showModal() {
            this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
        }

        closeModal() {
            this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div onClick={this.showModal}>
                    {this.props.title}
                    <Modal isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}>
                        <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
                        {this.props.notes}
                    </Modal>
                </div>
            );
        }

    }
```

The state just doesn't get updated if I check it in the developer tools and I have no idea why. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code, do you have any console errors? maybe add a `console.log` at the top of the render to see what the value of `this.state.modalIsOpen` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem, which was actually a bit strange - even if I logged `this.state.modalIsOpen` in the `setState` callback after it was set to `false`, the value was still `true`. At any rate, I changed the code to perform a toggle instead and it resolved the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/q38nzl9yy9

```
toggleModal() {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: !this.state.modalIsOpen });
}

render() {
    return (
    <div onClick={this.showModal}>
        {this.props.title}
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}>
        <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
        {this.props.notes}
        </Modal>
    </div>
    );
}
```

I'm still digging into why the `this` context seems to be getting muddled, since this appears to be a straightforward example.

Comment: Thanks man! Very strange indeed... Let me know if you got an explanation!

Comment: Wow, really concise way of writing a toggle for `this.setState`. I've always been using a ternary. Very nice!